# Form not submitted by p:commandButton when oncomplete is specified

Tags: jsf-2, primefaces, commandbutton

I'm using JSF 2 and Primefaces 5 and I have a problem using the onsucccess or oncomplete attribute on the commandButton component.

```
<p:commandButton value="Send" action="#{mybean.myMethod}" ajax="true" update=":myForm" process="@form" oncomplete="trackConv(id,value);" />
```

Many validations has to be performed, so that at the end (the javaScript (Google conversion) code is executed. When the oncomplete attribute is not there, the validation works. When I put the onsucccess or oncomplete attribute the validation doesn't work and nothing happens. The commandButton action is not fired at all! 
What am I missing here? Thanks

I have a second question, should I use onsuccess or oncomplete attribute to execute my Google conversion?

**EDIT:** 
I'm using both declarative (required field) and imperative (backing bean) validation.

Comment: Two things: 1: What validation? I don't see any. 2: Please create a separate question for each one.

Comment: @Kukeltje I edited my post. My code is very large, do you really want me to post it?

Comment: As to posting code snippets, read on SSCCE and MCVE: http://sscce.org and http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Comment: Look in your javascript console for clues